# How can I embed a Angular 5 app into HTML in another page?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, angular5

Well I am working with a project and using Angular 5.2.0 where I have done a component with their service and some modules. The company that want this component prefer include the angular app like a Widget in their page.

I am trying some code like this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48339911/using-angular-4-component-as-widget-on-a-static-website) and this [option](https://medium.com/@zamarrowski/how-to-develop-a-widget-with-angularjs-e2848bc5b875) but I don't understand how they are doing this. I want to know another way or a better explain about this issue.

Can I package all my app in a only javascript to include in the HTML page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I found it was use iframe tag in HTML. For example:

```
<iframe id="Example"
    title="Example"
    width="400"
    height="400"
    src="http://localhost/example">
</iframe>
```

Work fine. However, it's some slow. I hope help you.

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a custom Angular element and then use webcomponent polyfills (Still most browsers don't support web components natively) to load the angular element into any HTML page.

You can check the following URLs:

https://angular.io/guide/elements

https://blog.angulartraining.com/tutorial-how-to-create-custom-angular-elements-55aea29d80c5

Although I am not quite sure if it's supported in Angular 5. However Angular 6 does have support for custom elements.

Comment: It is not supported in Angular 5